# Azure Media Services - Download Transient Error

Tags: azure-media-services

I have a lot of audios in my database whose URLs are like:

```
https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/uploaded%2F735fe9dc-e568-4920-a3ed-67230ce01991%2F5998d1f8-1795-4776-a19c-f1bc4a0d4786%2F2020-08-13T13%3A09%3A13.0996703Z?sv=2020-02-10&se=2022-01-05T16%3A58%3A50Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=hQBPyOE92%2F67MqU%2Fe5V2NsqGzgPxogVeXQT%2BOlvbayw%3D
```

I am using these URLs as my JobInput, and submitting a encoding job, because I want to migrate the audios distribution to a streaming approach.
However, every time I use this kind of URL, it fails with DownloadTransientError, and a message something like `while trying to download the input files, the files were not acessible`.

If I manually upload a file to the blob storage with a simpler URL (https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/my-audio.wav), and use it as the JobInput, it works seamlessly. I suspect it has something to do with the special characters on the bigger URL, but I am not sure. What could be the problem?

Here is the part of the code that submits the job:

```
            var jobInput = new JobInputHttp(new[]
            {
                audio.AudioUrl.ToString()
            });
            JobOutput[] jobOutput =
            {
                new JobOutputAsset(outputAssetName),
            };


            var job = await client.Jobs.CreateAsync(
                    resourceGroupName: _azureMediaServicesSettings.ResourceGroup,
                    accountName: _azureMediaServicesSettings.AccountName,
                    transformName: TransformName,
                    jobName: jobName,
                    new Job
                    {
                        Input = jobInput,
                        Outputs = jobOutput
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the file name in the URL you're providing. I'll use your URL as an example, but unescape it as well so that it is more clear.  The URL should be something like https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/uploaded/735fe9dc-e568-4920-a3ed-67230ce01991/5998d1f8-1795-4776-a19c-f1bc4a0d4786/2020-08-13T13:09:13.0996703Z/my-audio.wav?sv=2020-02-10&se=2022-01-05T16:58:50Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=hQBPyOE92/67MqU/e5V2NsqGzgPxogVeXQT+Olvbayw=
Just include the actual blob name of the input video or audio file with the associated file extension.

Comment: Interesting. However, the name of the file in my blob storage is actually ```2021-02-16T04:27:34.5279015Z```. The file has no extension however. Could this be the problem?

Comment: The issue is more likely the filename itself then.  Media Services does encoding on Windows machines and filenames have to comply with what Windows itself supports: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#file-and-directory-names

Comment: Amazing. That was indeed the issue. I solved it by using ```JobInputAsset``` instead.